# characterization of infinite union of field being a field

Tags: abstract-algebra

This is related to existence of maximal abelian extension. I can prove this holds for maximal abelian extension and some other extensions by forming direct limit as ascending chain of union of fields via initial object. Let $F_\lambda$ be a family of field extension over a base field $K$ parametrized by $\lambda\in\Lambda$.

$\textbf{Q1:}$ Is $\cup_\lambda F_\lambda$ always a field? If $F_\lambda$ is the family of fields with repetition s.t. $|\{F_\lambda\}|<\infty$, then $\cup_\lambda F_\lambda$ is not necessarily a field as finite union of vector space might not be a vector space. However, it seems that infinite union of distinct fields is a field. Why this has to be the case? It seems that this holds for $F_\lambda$ with some property $P$.

$\textbf{Q2:}$ What characterizes $\cup_\lambda F_\lambda$ being a field for infinite union or direct limit? Or in other words, in the category of field extensions of $F$ over a base field $K$, the infinite union exists but not the finite union in general. (I am not assuming topological field condition here. And I guess this is irrelevant here at the moment.)

Comment: "it seems that infinite union of distinct fields is a field" – why?

Comment: @lhf I do not know. It holds for infinite union of abelian extensions and degree 2 extensions. I do not see any good reason this has to be the case.

Comment: @lhf The essential part I could see is that I can form ascending chain of fields s.t. each field is contained in some larger fields. Then it is reasonable to be a field. However, I do not see any good reason this holds for general case as I have not seen any obvious counter example.

Comment: @lhf I am wondering whether I can drop the condition for the existence of direct system which gives me existence of larger fields. However this is related to direct limit or infinite union.

Comment: We need a "filtered family". (Filtered w.r.t. inclusion of fields. This means that for each two fields $F_1,F_2$ in the family there is an $F_{12}$ containing them, not necessarily a maximum (w.r.t. inclusion) in the family, just one dominating both.)

Comment: @dan_fulea Filtered family to me is a direct system. Can this condition be dropped to maintain the limit being a field as in $Q2$?

Comment: Yes, directed system. We need it, else consider the finite family of three fields with $2, 2^5, 2^7$ elements. We really need the field with $2^{5\cdot 7}$ elements in the family. (There is also the other set-theoretical problem, when union is taken in a strict sense, the fields $\cong\Bbb F_4$ with elements $0,1,x,x+1$, respectively $0$, $1$, Peter, Peter$+1$, Peter$\ne x,x+1$ do not have a common place in the union. There is just one highlander field $\Bbb F_4$ up to isomorphism.)

Comment: @dan_fulea Sorry for asking repeated question. Is there such example for $F_i$ with $i\in I,|I|=\infty$ s.t. $\cup_iF_i$ is not a field? I mean dropping condition of directed system for infinite index set. Thanks.

Comment: @user45765 We can take the family $(F_p)_p$ of fields with $2^p$ elements, $p$ prime, all of them being extensions of the field with $2$ elements. General elements from two different fields cannot be added / multiplied inside the union of the family.

Comment: @dan_fulea Ah yes. Thanks a lot.